# Firestore rules don't seem to work with firebase node js API function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Firebase rule for a collection but it doesn't seem to work. Currently I am disallowing writes to the doc but it doesn't seem to have any effect when I try to update it. The rules fail when the database is interacted via the firebase node js API function.

```
    match /accounts/{accId} {
       allow read: if (request.auth != null &&
       ((resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid) || 
       (request.auth.uid == 'e6aaXxP6PsMWvuhCo6oOYqTTL8p2')));
       allow write: if false;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) that bypasses any security rules?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the nodejs SDK initialized with a service account, that code will always bypass security rules.  Security rules only apply to web and mobile applications using their platform SDKs.  They do not apply to any backend SDKs.  The assumption is that your code running on a secure backend is fully controlled by you and not subject to abuse.

Comment: Thank you @Doug Stevenson, that solved my problem and doubt.